# read and write a json file in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

okay I have this json file:

```
{   
    "joe": {
        "name": "joe",
        "lastName": "black"
    },

    "matt": {
        "name": "matt",
        "lastName": "damon"
    }
}
```

and I want to add a person with node.js:

```
{   
    "joe": {
        "name": "joe",
        "lastName": "black"
    },

    "matt": {
        "name": "matt",
        "lastName": "damon"
    },

    "brad": {
        "name": "brad",
        "lastName": "pitt"
    }
}
```

With the below code I am trying to read the json document, parse it, add the person, and then write again to file. However, the parsed object (jsonObj) is not recognized in the write function. I know it has to do with the event loop, but I am not sure how to solve it. I tried using process.nextTick, but can't get it to work.

```
var jsonObj;

fs.open('files/users.json', 'r+', function opened(err, fd) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    var readBuffer = new Buffer(1024),
        bufferOffset = 0,
        readLength = readBuffer.length,
        startRead = 0; 
    fs.read(fd, readBuffer, bufferOffset, readLength, startRead, function read(err, readBytes) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (readBytes > 0) {
            jsonObj = JSON.parse(readBuffer.slice(0, readBytes).toString());
            jsonObj["brad"] = {};
            jsonObj["brad"].name = "brad";
            jsonObj["brad"].lastName = "pitt";
        **//Until here it works fine and the 'jsonObj' is properly updated**
        }
    });
 });

process.nextTick(function () {
    var writeBuffer, 
        startWrite = 0,
        bufferPosition = 0,
        writeLength;
    fs.open('files/users.json', 'r+', function opened(err, fd) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        ***//Below I get the 'jsonObj is undefined' error***
        writeBuffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(jsonObj.toString(), null, '/\t/'));
        writeLength = writeBuffer.length;
        fs.write(fd, writeBuffer, bufferPosition, writeLength, startWrite, function wrote(err, written) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In node you can `require` json files:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var users = require('./names');

users.brad = {
  name: 'brad',
  lastName: 'pitt'
}

var string = JSON.stringify(users,null,'\t');

fs.writeFile('./names.json',string,function(err) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);
  console.log('done');
})
```

Optional async version without requiring:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./names.json',{encoding: 'utf8'},function(err,data) {
  var users = JSON.parse(data);
   users.brad2 = { name: 'brad', lastName: 'pitt' };
  var string = JSON.stringify(users,null,'\t');

  fs.writeFile('./names.json',string,function(err) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('done');
  })  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple hint is: if you need to use `process.nextTick`, something is wrong. Leave that function to the library programmers! :)

Just move the function you call with `nextTick` to `Until here...`

`nextTick` does not wait until you read that file (that might take a few hundret ticks!), it just waits for the next tick. And that is available the nanosecond you call `fs.read` - because after `fs.read` the nodejs main loop is idle until either the kernel returns some information about that file or someone tells nodejs what to do on the next tick.

Comment: well a more helpful answer would be setTimeOut, which works very well

Comment: Lol... no don't use setTimeout either

Comment: why not if I go setTimeOut(theWriteFunction, 100), after the read function, it works

Comment: What if that file grows bigger? What if your production env is one day with a network storage and that becomes slow? (Good luck debugging on that day...) And: why waste 997 ms? And from theoretical point of view: the software does just not what you want and works by accident.