# How to push data to external JSON file (Using jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push an data to array in external local JSON file using jQuery.

So any ideas?

I have tried this:

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
data.push('Something');
});
```

And it wont be pushed into local JSON file

Comment: u mean local json file ?

Comment: Yes that was i meant

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: @VigneshRaja Do you know how to make that work?

Comment: @AyadHussein jQuery is not meant for loading/writing any files locally. Browsers enforce security-related limitations accessing the local filesystem (and quite rightly so). Even if you turn off these restrictions for your browser, these aren't the right tools for the job.

Comment: At least show a sample of the file contents, and the modification you want to apply (before/after). And give us an example of where an example file would be.

Comment: @AyadHussein Explaining why you want to do this might help us too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in JavaScript with [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (or a [multitude of other languages/platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3538156/344029)) but not with a browser & jQuery.

Here's how to [read and write a json file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25832666/344029)

On the other hand, users could upload a JSON file to your server, where you modify the structure and send them a modified JSON file back as a download.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to write files using Javascript (can cause security problems through xss, csrf ..)

> No, JavaScript doesn't have access to writing files as this would be a huge
> security risk to say the least. If you wanted to get/store information server-
> side, though, you can certainly make an Ajax call to a PHP/ASP/Python/etc.
> script that can then get/store the data in the server. If you meant store data
> on the client machine, this is impossible with JavaScript alone. I suspect
> Flash/Java may be able to, but I am not sure.
>
> If you are only trying to store a small amount of information for an
> unreliable
> period of time regarding a specific user, I think you want cookies. I am not
> sure from your question what you are trying to accomplish, though.

[Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the files in a local client's machine. May be for development setup you can do it. But before you need to restart the browser with `file-access` flag set.

You [can see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080689/javascript-scan-and-create-link-files-from-a-folder/48081514#48081514) that describes the opening browser setup with the flag set.

Then, you can use the following code to read the data.

```
var data = [];
var url = "/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/test.json";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET",url,true);
req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(req.readyState === 4)
    {
        data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    }
};
req.send();
```

To write into the file you may [look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript). (Not sure it is working or not)